# Polymorphism unimplemented method. What people usually do?

Tags: ruby, oop, domain-driven-design, polymorphism

If I have a model like this:

```
class Media
  attr_reader :title, :created_at
end

class Video < Media
end

class Picture < Media
  attr_reader :image_url
end
```

So, in the `Picture` class there is one attribute that should not exist in the superclass. What people usually do when you want to retrieve all the media? Would you want to throw exception on the method `image_url`? Or how would you re-model it?

Comment: `extends` is not valid Ruby. The syntax for inheritance is `Foo < Bar`.

Comment: I can't type < in the textarea it would just truncate my code, so I use extends to represent that instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, since that's not true at all. I've edited your question with the correct syntax, and the `<` displays just fine.

Comment: Oh thanks, may be I just typed it with my crappy phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in all media, then you shouldn't care if it's a video or a picture. In other words, a method that accepts a collection of `Media` should not call any methods from `Media` descendants. If you need all pictures, then work with `Picture`, don't overgeneralize.

If you still do need to process all media while telling the types apart, you can branch on a type.

```
def process_media media
  media.each do |m|
    if m.is_a? Picture
      # work with picture
    elsif m.is_a? Video
      # work with video
    end
  end
end
```

An alternative is to use duck typing. That is, if it has a method `image_url`, then it must be some kind of a picture.

```
def process_media media
  media.each do |m|
    if m.respond_to? :image_url
      # work with picture
    elsif m.respond_to? :bitrate
      # work with video
    end
  end
end
```